# Rhetorical phrase analysis

Tags: rhetoric, rhetorical-devices, phrase-analysis

Is there a rhetorical device found from the following phrase?

> It won't cost you a thing, but it may save your life.

Comment: Can you add to this: the context - both the surrounding text and the circumstances in which you want to do this (a class, personal curiosity, and what sorts of rhetorical devices you are looking at already and didn't work?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't matter, but the sentence is ungrammatical, so discussions of it rhetoric are perhaps premature.

Comment: @John Lawler How is the sentence ungrammatical?

Comment: It's been corrected. The rhetorical device is under the left front fender.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **antithesis** with *cost/save* and *nothing/your life*

**antithesis** (n.)

> The rhetorical contrast of ideas by means of parallel arrangements of
> words, clauses, or sentences (as in "action, not words" or "they
> promised freedom and provided slavery") [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithesis)

> A figure of speech in which an opposition or contrast of ideas is
> expressed by parallelism of words that are the opposites of, or
> strongly contrasted with, each other, such as “hatred stirs up strife,
> but love covers all sins” [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/antithesis)

Comment: The antithesis here, if any, would be something like ***cheap*** in the first clause (*it won't cost you a thing*) and  ***invaluable*** in the second (*it may save your life*).